# Task :transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED Program type already present *.BuildConfig

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-buildconfig

I have an Android Studio (3.4.1) cocos2d-x project with multiple modules. My settings.gradle file defines the 3 modules:

```
include ':libcocos2dx'
project(':libcocos2dx').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/libcocos2dx')
include ':ToaTetrisApp'
project(':ToaTetrisApp').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'app')

include ':gameCircleSDK'
```

NOTE: gameCircleSDK does not need its projectDir set because the directory matches the module name inside proj.android

The problem I have is that when I build a release build of the application OR I try to Build->Generate Signed Bundle / APK I get the following error:

```
>Task :ToaTetrisApp:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.amazon.ags.BuildConfig","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

NOTE: com.amazon.ags.BuildConfig is an auto-generated class for the gameCircleSDK module. The AndroidManifest.xml for gameCircleSDK defines package="com.amazon.ags" and this is the only place that the package is defined.

I also searched my generated files and found only the expected BuildConfig.java files in the release folders: com.toa.tetris (ToaTetrisApp), com.amazon.ags (gameCircleSDK), org.cocos2dx.lib (cocos2d-x)

I have the following build.gradle files:

proj.android:build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

proj.android:app:build.gradle [ToaTetrisApp]

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.toa.tetris"
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 21
        versionName "4.5.1"
        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
                ndkBuild {
                    targets 'MyGame'
                    arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang'
                    //arguments 'V=1'
                    arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

                    def module_paths = [project.file("../../cocos2d").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/cocos").absolutePath,
                                        project.file("../../cocos2d/external").absolutePath]
                    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
                        module_paths = module_paths.collect {it.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')}
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(";")
                    }
                    else {
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(':')
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
                cmake {
                    targets 'MyGame'
                    arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                    cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect{it as String})
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "../../Resources"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
            ndkBuild {
                path "jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
        else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
            cmake {
                path "../../CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {

       release {
            <CONTENT REMOVED>
        }
        debug {
            <CONTENT REMOVED>
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }

            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                }
            }
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // delete previous files first
    delete "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}"

    variant.mergeAssetsProvider.get().doLast {
        copy {
            from "${buildDir}/../../../Resources"
            into "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}"
            exclude "**/*.gz"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../gameCircleSDK/libs', include:['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':libcocos2dx')
    implementation project(':gameCircleSDK')
}
```

proj.android:gameCircleSDK:build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            <CONTENT REMOVED>
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()
    //buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
}
```

proj.android:..:cocos2d:cocos:platform:android:libcocos2dx:build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            <CONTENT REMOVED>
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        aidl.srcDir "../java/src"
        java.srcDir "../java/src"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: '../java/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I have been searching and found many recommendations and tried many of them to no avail. Here are some of the things I've tried:

- I tried File->Invalidate Caches / Restart: NOTE: I originally had the same problem with my debug build and run and this is the solution that resolved that issue.
- I have tried running 'gradlew ToaTetrisApp:dependencies' and I don't see any reference to com.amazon.ags nor any duplicates. I'm not sure I fully understand the output, but it seems for the debug, release and tests the dependencies seem to be as expected
- I have, of course, tried to clean and rebuild many times, but to no avail
- I have added 'multiDexEnabled true' to my app:build.gradle file. I'm not sure whether this really did anything or whether I added it to the correct file. This didn't seem to resolve the issue
- I have tried to add 'afterEvaluate { generateReleaseBuildConfig.enabled = false }', but again, I wasn't sure which build.gradle to add this to so I couldn't get it to work

I'm hoping that someone can provide some explanation of what exactly this error means and how I can track down and resolve this issue myself. This project doesn't use a lot of external dependencies so I would expect that it would be easy to track down what is going on exactly and why this error shows up. If you would like to offer some suggestions then please let me know which gradle file you would like me to add the code to as that is often not mentioned.